# About the sequence: $1, 3, 8, 24, 29, 87, 92, ?...$ find $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, geometric-progressions

This is a classic and curious recurrence sequence used in logic tests. Your rule can be determined as follows:

for $n$ even: $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$

for $n$ odd: $a_n = a_{n-1} + 5$

That is, the ratio alternates with each term.

Will there be a single formula for $a_n$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: Presumably you mean 'is there a formula for $a_n$ in terms of $n$ alone'.

Comment: It's not on the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+3%2C+8%2C+24%2C+29%2C+87%2C+92&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Well, certainly a formula can be found for the even terms, using the recurrence $a_{2n}=3a_{2n-2}+5$ while for the odd terms as $a_{2n+1}=3(a_{2n-1}+5)$, or maybe I have those backwards... I don't care enough.  You could then find each of their respective closed forms easily enough as they are simple second order linear recurrence relations for which many methods exist.  You could then write it as a piecewise function, or if you dislike that you can mimic the piecewise nature of it by using tricks such as multiplying blocks by things like $\sin^2(n\pi/2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of a sneaky answer. The subsequence of only odd terms, $1,8,29,92,\ldots$, is listed in the OEIS as sequence [A116952](https://oeis.org/A116952), $b_n=3b_{n-1} + 5$ with $b_0=1$ and has the explicit formula $b_n=\frac723^n-\frac52$. So then, the even terms satisfy $c_n=3b_n=3\left(\frac723^n-\frac52\right)$. Simple indicator functions for odd and even numbers outputting $1$ and $0$ can be constructed as $\frac{\pm(-1)^n+1}{2}$ so we have the explicit formula

$$\begin{align}a_n=\left(\frac{7}{2}3^{\frac{n-1}{2}}-\frac{5}{2}\right)\left(\frac{-\left(-1\right)^{n}+1}{2}\right)+3\left(\frac{7}{2}3^{\frac{n-1-1}{2}}-\frac{5}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}+1}{2}\right)
\\
\\
=\frac14\left[{7\cdot3^{{n}/{2}}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-20+\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(7\cdot3^{{n}/{2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-10\right)}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you Jam! great generic solution! congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

For an even value
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{2n}=3a_{2n-1}=5+3 a_{2n-2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Iterate this
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{2n}=5+3\times 5 +3^2 \times 5 + \cdots 3^{n-1} \times 5 +3^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
Sum the geometric series 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{2n}=5\frac{3^{n}-1}{3-1}+3^n = \frac{7 \times 3^n -5}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}